# grid with random image sizes and responsive

Tags: php, html, css

I have very small knowledge about PHP and HTML, so I need some help.

I'm trying to make my forum homepage (the gate) grid by getting images from the post, changing its size, and adding it to the page. For example:

[image: example screen shot]

Anyway, the code that i have is:

```html
{else}
<?php $t= 0;?>
<table class="grid" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" align="center">

<tr class="row">

{Des::while}{LastNews_subjectList}
<?php
if ($PowerBB->_CONF['info_row']['portal_columns'] == '1' )
{
$columns_News = "3";
}
else
{
$columns_News = "2";
}
if($t== $columns_News){
$t=0;
echo "</tr><tr>";
}?>
<td class="post-position" valign="top">
<table class="cell" border="1" width="100" class="border" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td class="rowthumb" valign="top">

<a href="index.php?page=topic&amp;show=1&amp;id={$LastNews_subjectList['id']}" title="<?php echo $title;?>">
<?php
$x = 1;

$images = array();
$PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['text'] = stripslashes($PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['text']);
preg_match_all('/src=([\'"])?((?(1).*?|\S+))(?(1)\1)/', $PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['text'], $images);
foreach ($images[2] as $src)
  {
 if($src)
  {
     echo '<img border="0" width="200" height="200" src="'.$src.'" alt="'.$PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['title'].'">';
  }

     break;
 }
  if(!preg_match_all('/src=([\'"])?((?(1).*?|\S+))(?(1)\1)/', $PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['text'], $images))
  {
   echo '<img border="0" width="200" height="200" src="look/portal/images/traffic_cone.png" alt="'.$PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['title'].'">';
  }

?>
</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cell-title" valign="top">

<?php
$PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['title'] = $PowerBB->Powerparse->censor_words($PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['title']);
$title = $PowerBB->_CONF['template']['while']['LastNews_subjectList'][$this->x_loop]['title'];
$num = "20";
$title = $PowerBB->functions->words_count($title,$num);?>
<a href="index.php?page=topic&amp;show=1&amp;id={$LastNews_subjectList['id']}" title="<?php echo $title;?>"><?php echo $title;?></a>
 <br />
<a href="index.php?page=topic&amp;show=1&amp;id={$LastNews_subjectList['id']}" title="Read More">
<div id="read_more_button">
{$lang['SubjectVisitor']}:
 ({$LastNews_subjectList['visitor']})
              &nbsp;{$lang['usercp_reputations']}:
  ({$LastNews_subjectList['rating']})
</div>
</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table> <br />
</td>
<?php $t= $t+1;?>
{/Des::while}
 </tr>
 </table>

{if {$PagerLastNews}}
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr>
<tr>
<td class="row3">
<span class="r-right">
{$PagerLastNews}
</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

So what do I have to do? I have tried several times and played around but I cant do it, so I hope I find the answer here.

Thanks in advance! goodbye.

Comment: so whats wrong with your code? please describe the problem that you are experiencing. **"but i cant do it"** doesnt really help with figuring out why your code isnt working.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use table for this. If you want to reach the layout you attached as an image for example.
I do not know how you collect the images, but of course you need them.
This library can help you out with the grid thingie. I used that, so I know. It should help you out. It has examples too, how to implement it for your site.
[Masonry - Cascading Grid Layout library](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Because of the comment...

You get the images in a PHP array. Print them out. The result should be something like this:

```
    <ul class="js-masonry" id="gallery-container">

<li class="grid-sizer"></li>

    <li class="item">
    <img alt="Test title 1" src="/cache/b/6/9/f/c/b69fcffb670eb78227c9f407bf7fcc4db94f4c13.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>

    <li class="item">
    <img alt="Test title 23" src="/cache/c/1/f/0/0/c1f0045723688ac91a92ac9b49ea13c00bbb1683.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>

    <li class="item">
    <img alt="Test title 2" src="/cache/5/1/7/1/a/5171a4e0264f19486a8033fffcf8e1a0e62d0587.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </li>

    </ul>
```

You download the js library. And include it:
(or use the CDN as i use here for dev...)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then run the script, after the page downloads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $container = $('#gallery-container').masonry();
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry(
                { 
                    "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer", 
                    "itemSelector": ".item", 
                    "gutter":10
                });
    });

});
</script>
```

As you can see I used the imagesLoaded library also. 
[imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/)

Comment: I could do it after reading the docs. If the link changes, at least you know what to search for... I extended the answer, what got -1. My opinion is a programmer can do it based upon these infos. Cheers.... 
@Paulie_D

Comment: i get the first image from every post automatically this code is doing so but the problem the way he view it i want it to be like the example up there but look like that       http://i.imgur.com/zG8qiCJ.png       so i want to convert the code but  don't know how